# Product Images Getting Auto Deleted everyday in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

On our website, Some weird thing is Happening. From Past 7 days, everyday the product images disappear (from the Front end) for some particular sku's and when we reupload the excel file then everything works fine. Then next day again the images gets disappeared.

Steps That we have taken till Now:

1. Changed Re-indexing Settings to manual.
2. Checked Cron File
3. Have Uploaded Some New Products Manually.

Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the stock/price sync. or products import scripts? Did you check or image files are deleted from server? It looks like that the scheduled script updates the products with wrong data.